# Smash product of an infinite family of pointed spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, product-space

Is the smash product also defined for an infinite family of pointed spaces?
In section 7.9 of his book *Algebraic Topology*, tom Dieck defines this in the compactly generated context:

[image]

Tom Dieck defines a $k$-space to be a space $X$ such that every $k$-closed subset is closed in $X$ where $A\subset X$ is said to be $k$-closed if for every compact Hausdorff space $K$ and every continuous map $f: K\to X$, the preimage $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $K$.

For those $k$-spaces, the smash product is associative, but it is not associative in the category of all pointed spaces. However, one could still define

$$ \bigwedge_j X_j := \Big(\prod_j X_j\Big) \Big/ W_JX_j. $$

Is this a common definition? Or shouldn't we do this because of the missing associativity?

Thank you for any help and comments!

Comment: What is a $k$-space?

Comment: I have added the definition.